# delendent dropdown in django(DJango,Python)

Tags: python, django, dropdown

I want to make four drop down button(like country state city and location)each field we want to make it based on the selection like when country select its state related to country we get and when state is s selected then city related to these state gets populated when city get slelected then its loctation related to these city we get

Comment: Actually, this will be easy to maintain from frontend side instead of backend.

Answer (score 0):

One of approach you can take is :

1. User go to page
2. Back End get the list of country and pass it to front end
3. User select 1 country from drop-down
4. Front end java-script use ajax call to pass country to back-end and get all states
5. Front end show all states in second drop-down
6. User select 1 state from drop-down
7. Front end java-script use ajax call to pass state to back-end and get all district
8. Front end show all district in third drop-down

but this kind of slow, so choose wisly